# Microphone supply circuit comparison?

Tags: microphone, electret, virtual-ground

I'm going to connect an electret mic (WM-61A) to my computer's "mic in", and am very confused on the reasoning behind a couple different diagrams/schematics that could possibly be used to do this with.

The first one is from a thread on Head-Fi and seems to be the standard that everyone uses there:

[image]

This is good to me, but then when I did a search for a couple different options, I found this:

[image]

There's also another schematic using an AD654 op-amp specifically for phantom power. The one above claims to provide a "Phantom Ground"; what exactly is this compared to the first schematic and compared to a virtual ground? Could any of these be used for my purpose?

Please and thank you for any guidance given!

Comment: Granted this is a dusty old thread, but either I'm missing something, or "AD633A" doesn't exist (Google suggests "AD633" analog multiplier!), and AD654 is a V-to-F converter? As for the original title, "phantom power" is a specific thing (48V for professional application) which is not being discussed here. FWIW, sound cards bias the output, making the whole circuit redundant: just hook up the electret and go.

Comment: You show a +9V battery but wrongly show a second -9V battery making an 18V supply which will probably damage the mic that has a max allowed voltage of 10V. Use only one +9V and 0V battery of your computer does not power an electret mic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra circuits you have researched do not apply if all you are trying to do is interface an electret microphone to a computer mic-in port.

Those extra circuits produce a mid-rail voltage (such as 4.5 volts when using a 9 volt battery) and are useful when developing an op-amp amplifier circuit and all you have is a single power supply such as a 9 volt battery. The mid-rail voltage can be regarded as ground for any audio inputs or outputs. It is sometimes called "phantom" or "virtual" ground but I prefer the term "midrail generator" because it says what it does. You don't need this for what you are wanting to do.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know. I figured they weren't the same as they looked to make a virtual ground, or else called "midrail generator" like you said. I have a better understanding now, so thank you very much!

Comment: Currency of thanks is upvoting or formal acceptance of an answer but leave it a day to see if any new answers come along that might be better.